# How do I use PowerShell to make nightly backups of a network-accessed company file server to SharePoint Online?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

We are migrating our file server to SharePoint Online. I already know how to use the SharePoint migration tool and such to upload our entire drive to a site. We do not, however, want to get rid of our file server (S:) entirely as many internal applications rely on it for uploading data and cannot point towards Internet sites. We're trying to synchronize our local directory with a SharePoint directory using a PowerShell script so that the SharePoint site can stay updated as new data is added to the S:\ drive. The script we used is able to copy an entire folder to SharePoint, but cannot recognize sub-folders and cannot differentiate between new files and files that are already on SharePoint. We want a script that can do a one-way sync of our drive to the site, including all sub-folders and files, but that only uploads new or modified files. We also do not want to sync SharePoint changes back down to the server as we are trying to cut down on storage usage. The code looks like this (with generic placeholders for locations):

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
 
#Script settings
 
$webUrl = "http://vs-server12"
 
$docLibraryName = "Documents"
$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared%20Documents"
 
$localFolderPath = "C:\temp\Docs4SharePoint"
 
#Open web and library
 
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
 
$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]
 
$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles()
 
ForEach($file in $files)
{
 
    #Open file
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()
 
    #Add file
    $folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)
 
    write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
    write-host "Success"
 
    #Close file stream
    $fileStream.Close();
}
 
#Dispose web
 
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do a one-direction migration of folders, subfolders, and files through PowerShell. I've tested this command on a couple different locations and have tried it multiple times with it being successful each time. If you download the SharePoint Migration Tool from Microsoft, alongside the gui you also get some new PowerShell modules specifically designed for the task. Commands such as Register-SPMTMigration, Add-SPMTTask, and StartSPMTMigration allow you to specify locations to push to SharePoint. The PowerShell modules support taking data from file shares and taking files from SharePoint on-premise. When you run the command it will also only migrate any edited or new files since the last migration, meaning it won't waste bandwidth and time reuploading every single file to SharePoint. This makes it perfect as a nightly backup solution for my needs.
You can use pscredentials to allow the process to be automated, otherwise you have to sign into Office every time you run the command. Here is an example I made (with personal data taken out, and with two extra parameters set).

```
# Define clear text string for username and password
[string]$userName = 'USERNAME'
[string]$userPassword = 'PASSWORD'

# Convert to SecureString
[securestring]$secStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force

# Create PS Credential Object

[pscredential]$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userName, $secStringPassword)

Register-SPMTMigration -SPOCredential $Credentials -MigrateFileVersionHistory $false -DeleteTempFilesWhenMigrationDone $true

Add-SPMTTask -FileShareSource C:\Path -TargetSiteUrl https://sharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/Test -TargetList Documents

Start-SPMTMigration
```